# Can't access subfolders in a mapped network drive

Tags: windows

So I have a shared network drive, Z:, which I've mapped to my current computer (which I am admin of). I can access the top-level folders that show up when I open Z:, I just can't access any of the subfolders. Windows spits the error: Z:\Existence (or any other subfolder) is not accessible.

Anyone have any ideas as to what is happening? It's accepting my credentials at the top level, so I'm not sure why it's not letting me access those subfolders.

ACL info for the Z: drive, which I can access:

[image]

ACL info for a Z: subfolder, which I cannot access:

[image]

When I try to cd in using the cmd prompt, I get the following error message: "user name or password is incorrect".

When I try powershell, some folders, which appear in the folder window, give the error "cannot find path Z:\ because it does not exist".

Comment: Provide us the ACL information on a folder you can access and a folder you cannot access.  You being a Administrator on your machine does not mean you have access to a folder, although as an Administrator, you can take ownership of (almost) any folder.

Comment: At work now (this issue is for my home network), but I will put that info up as soon as I get back.

Comment: ACL info screenshots have been added.

Comment: If you try to `cd` into or `dir` in a subfolder in a command prompt or PowerShell, does it give you a more specific error message?

Comment: It just returns "the user name or password is incorrect", but I've used this exact user name and password to log in multiple times before... Will add this info to the question. When I use powershell, it tells me that some folders don't actually exist, even though they appear on the Windows folder directory.

Comment: I assume you've already tried unmapping\disconnecting the drive letter and then remapping it too? Should be easy enough to complete just in case.

Comment: Yep, tried that. No luck.